# Is there a 'skip-test-framework' option for Ember CLI?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

In Rails, it's possible to invoke a generator command but tell it to not generate any tests via `--skip-test-framework` or `--no-test-framework`.

Is there a similar flag for Ember CLI?

For example, if I want to `ember generate controller MyController` and NOT have it auto-generate a test for that controller, is there a flag I can pass?

Comment: You actually can prevent creating tests for certain `ember-cli` generators, by overriding the blueprints for the tests to do nothing, read here for more https://ember-cli.com/extending/

The biggest catch is you can't turn it off or on with a flag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No Dmitri Zagidulin, you're unable to generate a controller or other files without creating tests. The idea was suggested June 18 of 2015 but was shot down.

https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/4310

Comment: Note that it _is_ possible to run a generator without creating tests. But you have to modify your generators-- there's no CLI flag. The details are in https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/4310.